# How to add two columns in pivot table (Excel)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, categorical-data

I am trying to find a way to have two categorical variables in a pivot table? (instead of a drop down within the same column)
The way that it automatically works is not really practical to futher manipulate the data and it seems like such a simple feature I hope it must exist somewhere in the pivot table settings.

Illustration of my question below:
[image]

Thanks!

I tried adding my second categrical variable as column but it just created many columns for each of the categories for my variable, instead of filling the column with the categories.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following options under Design > Report Layout:

- Show in Tabular Form
- Repeat All Item Labels

[image]